# How do I access this object property with an illegal name?

Tags: php, object

I'm using a PHP class someone wrote to interface with the BaseCamp API.

The particular call I'm doing is to retrieve the items in a todo list, which works fine.

My problem is, I'm not sure how to access just the `todo-items` property of the object that is returned. Here's the var_dump of the returned object:

```
object(stdClass)[6]
  public 'completed-count' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'description' => string 'Description String' (length=89)
  public 'id' => string '12345' (length=7)
  public 'milestone-id' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'name' => string 'Error Reports' (length=13)
  public 'position' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'private' => string 'false' (length=5)
  public 'project-id' => string '58904' (length=7)
  public 'tracked' => string 'false' (length=5)
  public 'uncompleted-count' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'todo-items' => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'todo-item' => 
        object(stdClass)[5]
          public 'completed' => string 'false' (length=5)
          public 'content' => string 'content string here' (length=133)
          public 'created-on' => string '2009-04-16T20:33:31Z' (length=20)
          public 'creator-id' => string '23423' (length=7)
          public 'id' => string '234' (length=8)
          public 'position' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'responsible-party-id' => string '2844499' (length=7)
          public 'responsible-party-type' => string 'Person' (length=6)
          public 'todo-list-id' => string '234234' (length=7)
  public 'complete' => string 'false' (length=5)
```

How can I access the `todo-items` portion of this object?

Answer (score 298, accepted):

```
<?php
$x = new StdClass();
$x->{'todo-list'} = 'fred';
var_dump($x);
```

So, `$object->{'todo-list'}` is the sub-object.  If you can set it like that, then you can also read it the same way:

```
echo $x->{'todo-list'};
```

Another possibility:

```
$todolist = 'todo-list';
echo $x->$todolist;
```

If you wanted to convert it to an array, which can be a little more easily (ie the obvious `$ret['todo-list']` accessing), this code is taken almost verbatim from Zend_Config  and will convert for you.

```
public function toArray()
{
    $array = array();
    foreach ($this->_data as $key => $value) {
        if ($value instanceof StdClass) {
            $array[$key] = $value->toArray();
        } else {
            $array[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Although that's short and sweet (and what I'd recommend), you can also do this via variables: `$todolist='todo-list'; $x->$todolist`

Comment: *Very late response*, with PHP > 5.5, there are better solutions.  Either `cast` the object to an array, or try `get_object_vars()`.

Comment: @christian Very nice! But try $x->{$todolist}

Comment: @JamesBailey, right. For some reason, at that time I thought this was available only in newer versions of PHP, but it's been there since a while apparently: https://3v4l.org/nf15N

Answer (score 31):

Try this simplest way!

```
$obj = $myobject->{'mydash-value'};
$objToArray = array($obj);
```

Comment: Good answers accompany code samples with an explanation for future readers. While the person asking this question may understand your answer, explaining how you arrived at it could help countless others.

Comment: Oh this is the REAL answer. I was trying forever to access an object property name with a '.' in it and this cleaned that right up!