# PHP: Access the value of an object where the key contains a '$'

Tags: php, object, echo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access a PHP object attribute having a dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093169/how-do-i-access-a-php-object-attribute-having-a-dollar-sign)

How do I access the value of an object where the key contains a '$'. I have an array named "entries" as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$t] => xyz
                )
        )
)
```

I want to access the value of [$t], ie. xyz. The following command returns null:

```
echo $entries[0]->id->$t;
```

What syntax should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `{expression}` syntax:

```
$entries[0]->id->{'$t'}
```

In case you are curious: `echo $entries[0]->id->$t;` would work if you did `$t = '$t';` first.