# Pulling apart stdclass with PHP

Tags: php, json, stdclass

I'm trying to access part of an StdClass that has a property #text. PHP uses '#' for comments so I'm having trouble getting PHP to parse it not as a comment. An example of the StdClass is below

`stdClass Object
    (
        [artist] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => John Denver
                [mbid] => 34e10b51-b5c6-4bc1-b70e-f05f141eda1e
                [url] => http://www.last.fm/music/John+Denver
                [image] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [#text] => http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/521025.jpg
                                [size] => small`

and I've tried to access it with:

```
$json->artist->image[0]->#text
```

but how can I escape the '#' or tell php to interpret it differently. Or is there another format to find the #text property.

I also tried:

```
$json['artist']['image'][0]['#text']
```

but I get an error. I'm sure this is something simple but it's really got me at the moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access a PHP object attribute having a dollar sign?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093169/how-do-i-access-a-php-object-attribute-having-a-dollar-sign)

Comment: Second parameter for json_decode() set to TRUE. Did you try that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access such properties with the following code:

```
$object->{'#text'}
```

Comment: To easy. I thought it may be something easy like that. Cheers very much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be JSON data, so when decoding, you can also set the second parameter to true:

```
$json = json_decode($input, true);
```

Now you are able to use this:

```
$json['artist']['image'][0]['#text']
```

Answer (score 0):

Citing another answer you can put the key in a variable an accessing it via this variable.

`$var='myvarwithstrangecharacters$asdfas#';`

`$object->$var;//do whatever you want`

from:
[How do I access a PHP object attribute having a dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093169/how-do-i-access-a-php-object-attribute-having-a-dollar-sign)