# How do I access a PHP object attribute having a @ sign?

Tags: php, variables, special-characters

My problem is similar to this one

[How do I access a PHP object attribute having a dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093169/how-do-i-access-a-php-object-attribute-having-a-dollar-sign)

but I have an @ (at) sign instead of a dollar.

The object is this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) { 
  ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { 
  ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" 
  ["href"]=> string(62) "http://someurl.com/images/193/image_normal.jpg" 
  ["rel"]=> string(5) "image" 
  } 
}
```

and I have to access the @attributes variable (the href component, really), but PHP doesn't allow such a syntax:

```
$object->@attributes
```

Following the cited resource, I tried either this way:

```
$object->{'@attributes'};
```

or

```
$myvar = '@attributes';
$object->$myvar;
```

but neither of the two forms leads to access the variable. It prints:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (0) {}
```

while I would expect a vector.

Any idea? thanks

Comment: You posted the duplicate yourself. The solution is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its is `attributes` see [SimpleXMLElement::attributes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) for more information

Example

```
foreach($xml->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

Comment: Only the second answer works for me. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

In normal cases `$object->{'@attributeName'}` - to ask your question.

But, you want to get an [xml element's attribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5346), with SimpleXMLElement - which is done like this:

```
$attributeValue = (string) $xmlElement['attributeName'];
```

More usage:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php