# php simplexml - extract large number on cdata

Tags: php, simplexml, cdata

I have the following part of my xml:

```
<book number="AB 123" type="SCI">
  <info>
    <type code="FIC"><![CDATA[Fiction]]></status>
    <publish-time><![CDATA[20090110214000]]></publish-time>
  </info>
</book>
```

If I do:

```
echo $key->info->type;
```

I get nice and easy "Fiction"

BUT if I do:

```
echo $key->info->publish-time;
```

I get "0".

I thought it might have to do with this (20090110214000) being a number, but I tried various ways to extract that but with no success. When I `print_r` I see the 20090110214000 just fine in there but why can I not get that value (as a number or string) to be echoed or assign it to a variable?

Comment: See as well: [SimpleXML Reading node with a hyphenated name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3626901/367456)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is `$key->info->publish - time`, basically a substraction of an undefined value minus an unknown constant (results in 0).

Use `$key->info->{'publish-time'}` to retrieve the correct value.

Comment: Sweeeeeeeeeeeeet! Thanks a lot!!