# How do i use SimpleXml when there are non alpha characters in the xml element name

Tags: php, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SimpleXML Reading node with a hyphenated name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626901/simplexml-reading-node-with-a-hyphenated-name)

I have some xml which has non alpha characters in the element names, such as '.' or '-'

e.g.

```
<MyXML>
    <SomeData>
        <Period.InTheMiddle>Data i want to get</Period.InTheMiddle>
    </SomeData>
</MyXML>
```

Now using $xml->SomeData->Period.InTheMiddle to get at the data won't work. So what do I have to do to be able to use elements that have '.' or '-' in their name?

Comment: Have you tried `$xml->SomeData->{"Period.InTheMiddle"}` ?

Comment: @ircmaxell I know i'm newer to SO, but I was searching for unanswered questions to see if I have some answers, and came accross this, IMO you should answer the question and @Matt shoud accept the answer, so it will not show in "unanswered" anymore.