# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: Accessing custom attributes

Tags: php, dom, attributes

I want to access a custom attribute that I added to some elements in an HTML file, here's an example of the `littleBox="somevalue"` attribute

```
<div id="someId" littleBox="someValue">inner text</div>
```

The Following doesn't work:

```
foreach($html->find('div') as $element){
 echo $element;
 if(isset($element->type)){
 echo $element->littleBox;
   }
}
```

I saw an article with a similar problem, but I couldn't replicate it for some reason. Here is what I tried:

```
function retrieveValue($str){
if (stripos($str, 'littleBox')){//check if element has it
$var=preg_split("/littleBox=\"/",$str);
//echo $var[1];
$var1=preg_split("/\"/",$var[1]);
echo $var1[0];
}
else
return false;
}
```

When ever I call the `retrieveValue()` function, nothing happens. Is `$element` (in the first PHP example above) not a string? I don't know if I missed something but it's not returning anything.

Here's the script in it's entirety:

```
<?php
require("../../simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$html = file_get_html($_POST['webURL']);

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('div') as $element){
    echo $element;
   if(isset($element->type)!= false){
    echo retrieveValue($element);
   }
}
}


function retrieveValue($str){
if (stripos($str, 'littleBox')){//check if element has it
$var=preg_split("/littleBox=\"/",$str);
//echo $var[1];
$var1=preg_split("/\"/",$var[1]);
return $var1[0];
}
else
return false;
}

?>

<form method="post">
Website URL<input type="text" name="webURL">
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why exactly can't you use [`DOM`](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$html->getElementById("someId")->getAttribute('littleBox');
```

You could also use SimpleXML:

```
$html = '<div id="someId" littleBox="someValue">inner text</div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($html);
$div = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
echo $div->attributes()->littleBox;
```

**I would advice against using regex to parse html** but shouldn't this part be like this:

```
$str = $html->getElementById("someId")->outertext;
$var = preg_split('/littleBox=\"/', $str);
$var1 = preg_split('/\"/',$var[1]);
echo $var1[0];
```

Also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8851091/1059001

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that is the one that I'm confused on (link you provided). I tried the same thing, but it doesn't return the value of the custom attribute. I'll try the id suggestion, but the id is something that may vary and I won't know the specific id.

Comment: See above $html->getElementById("someId")->outertext;

Comment: this is what I'm trying: `// Find all divs 
foreach($html->find('div') as $element){
$str = $element->outertext;
$var = preg_split('/littleBox=\"/', $str);
$var1 = preg_split('/\"/',$var[1]);
echo $var1[0];
}`

Comment: You can do it with SimpleXML see my revised answer. I just tested it and it works. That way you don't need any external libraries.

Comment: Wow that's cool, just one more thing... I'm using an external file, `file_get_xml('file.ext')`, how how would you do it with the external file? The file is HTML.

Comment: `$html = file_get_contents(...path to file...)` 
or
`$dom = new DOMDocument; $dom->loadHTMLFile(...path to file...)`

Comment: I'm soooo sorry, I thought I did. There you go though. Thanks again!

Comment: This $html->getElementById("someId")->getAttribute('littleBox'); does exactly what I want. Thanks buddy !

Answer (score 0):

See that http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/ it's like jQuery but on php. Very strong library.

Comment: If you use phpquery you should know that it is pretty a dead project now. Since there haven't been updates for a few years.

Comment: does anyone know how to access custom attributes using the above stuff? Or a workaround?