# extract data from within html tags to mysql with php

Tags: php, html, sql, curl, web-scraping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: Accessing custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559796/php-simple-html-dom-parser-accessing-custom-attributes)

I'm searching for a way to import data from html tags to sql. The webpage is on an external server.

I have a website with this string;

```
<div class="item_1" value_1="1a" value_2="1b" value_3="1c">
  some text which i don't want to import into sql
</div>

<div class="item_2" value_1="2a" value_2="2b" value_3="2c">
  some text which i don't want to import into sql
</div>
```

I would like to store the class and value_1, value_2 and value_3 attributes to a mySQL database using a php script file.

I have set up a cURL script to export the data to a text file but this includes all text and not just the attributes that I need. And I was only able to echo the results as HTML.

Can someone please enlighting me on how to do this. If it is even possible....

Comment: And this is not data mining. This barely is web scraping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an HTML parser like this one: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Or you can just parse through it like text (simple or w. RegEx)

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is a bad idea.  http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html

Comment: @AndyLester -  I agree and that link is helpful - it still remains an option though and I think HTML parsers are the ideal solution.