# Cannot parse nodes in SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SimpleXML Reading node with a hyphenated name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626901/simplexml-reading-node-with-a-hyphenated-name)

I have XML with nodes contain dashes:

```
  <max-passwd-length>32</max-passwd-length>
  <max-email-length>128</max-email-length>
```

I used these lines:

```
$s = simplexml_load_file('rss-0.91.xml');
print $s->max-email-length->title
```

But I get PHP error because there are dashes, what can I do to solve this issue?

P.S. I cannot edit the XML file to remove dashes.

Comment: XML Tag Name Rules : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `$s->{'max-email-length'}->title`