# Finding the value of a special attribute

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

So I'm using PHP and simple_html_dom to scrape a webpage.

I'm trying to retrieve the attribute value of "data-event-period" here but I don't know how to do it.

```
<tr class="esEventRow0 event85 period3 esEventTime1379436584.1431 video" data-event-period="3" data-event-timeperiod="530" data-event-id="85" data-event-class="Goal" data-event-type="3-2" data-video-id="2672313886001">
```

My code looks like this:

```
$html = file_get_html("log.htm");

foreach($html->find('table#esEventList tr[class^="esEventRow0"]') as $row) {
    if($row->find('td.esGCTime', 0)) {
        $time = $row->find('td.esGCTime', 0)->plaintext;
        echo $row->class; #this returns "esEventRow0 event102 period3 esEventTime1379436584.1592"
        echo $row->data-event-period; #this returns the error "Notice: Use of undefined constant event - assumed 'event' in"
    }
}
```

Best regards!

Comment: Did you try using `$row->getAttribute ('data-event-period')` instead? Maybe an issue with the hyphens?

Comment: It really was that easy huh.. Wow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's choking on the hyphen.  Try using `$row->{'data-event-period'}`

As explained in: [SimpleXML Reading node with a hyphenated name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626901/simplexml-reading-node-with-a-hyphenated-name/3626928#3626928)