# How to read SimpleXML-Object value where the tag has a special character in it?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Hi guys! I need your help here..
I'm creating a simple XML-Reader in PHP/HTML atm and I've came across a problem.
One XML-Tag has a special character in it ("-") like:

```
<some-tag>foobar</some-tag>
```

How do I escape a character, while assigning a variable?

```
$value = $xml->some-tag
```

Doesn't work because PHP sees the character as an operator..
I've tried it with:

```
$value = $xml->'some-tag'
```

but that 'obviously' didn't work either.
Also this is my first post, so sorry in advance for any mistakes or broken rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can use the content of a variable as a variable.

In your case you can do:

```
$myTagName = "some-tag";
$value = $xml->$myTagName;
```

**EDIT**
According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/3626928/4641073 you can use:

```
$value = $xml->{'some-tag'};
```