# Accessing stdClass variable name that start's with an integer value

Tags: php, arrays, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access this object property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758449/how-do-i-access-this-object-property)

The data returned in a request is (JSON):

```
stdClass Object
(
[USD] => stdClass Object
    (
        [7d] => 23.3414
```

I'm calling:

```
json_decode(...);
```

And trying to access it via:

```
echo $json->USD->7d;
```

But that fails, because the variable name cannot start with an integer. Is there any syntax in PHP for accessing this?

Otherwise I would fix this by doing:

```
$set = (array) $json->USD;
echo $set['7d'];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is working:

```
$name = '7bar';
$o->$name = 'foo';
echo $o->{'7bar'};
```

As you see in the example there are two different ways to access variables with uncommon names.

Comment: Cool      echo $json->USD->{'7d'};    that worked.

Answer (score 5):

```
json_decode($var, true);
```

sets object to an assoc array, not your answer but saves typecast call.

Comment: +1 cool, I'm'a use this, thanks. But I'm going accept "flori"s answers as the *correct* one.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the variable name from 7d to something like d7? Is there a reason for the 7d reference?

Comment: Its not my data, its the response to API request.