# Couchdb with PHP How to work with parameters containing a point?

Tags: php, couchdb, point

I have a problem.  I should receive attachment parameters, but with a point it doesn't work:

```
if (isset($doc->doc->_attachments->ico.gif)) //Error 500
```

How should it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have PHP here to check, but if the problem is with the ".", perhaps the syntax mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758449/how-do-i-access-this-object-property) will help, ie

```
<?php
if (isset($doc->doc->_attachments->{'ico.gif'}))
```