# What is @ in an object property?

Tags: php

I have the following object:

```
[Suppliers] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [@size] => 1
                    [name] => Supplier Name
                    [Supplier] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [@chainCode] => EP
                            [@id] => 13
                        )

                )
```

I know how to get the `name` property and display it, but I don't know how to get the properties that start with an '@' sign ... What is it and how can I get its value?

Comment: Could they possibly be private/static members? Not sure I've ever seen an `@property` before.

Comment: What produces this output? `var_dump`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's just properties with a somewhat unusual name. You can fetch them like this:

```
$object->{'@id'};
```

Comment: The output is produced by an API ... I've tried your way and it worked! Thanks mate! I've googled for 2 hours about it and nothing!

Comment: Maybe you were looking in the wrong place? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758449/how-do-i-access-this-object-property