# PHP access object property @property after JSON decode

Tags: php, json

After doing a JSON decode, I get the following:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [@type] => d
            [@rid] => #8:0
            [@version] => 4
            [@class] => users
            [email] => xyz@something.com
            [username] => SomeName
            [password] => password
            [out] => Array
                (
                    [0] => #7:1
                )

        )

...
```

How do I access the `@rid` or `@class` properties of the object?

Comment: Do you need an object from json_decode, or would you like an array instead?

Comment: you might also be able to do $obj->{'@rid'}

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is @ in an object property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034401/what-is-in-an-object-property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$t = json_decode($var, true)` to get an associative array back<sup>1</sup>
Then you can access it via `$t['@type']`

<sub><sup>1</sup> [2nd parameter of json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode#refsect1-function.json-decode-parameters): When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You can access those variables using: `$obj->{"@type"}`.

Comment: This works for me and keeps my code pattern. Thank you!