# How do I get the value of a @ object attribute?

Tags: javascript, object

So I'm getting some JSON data containing 12 objects. outputting the objects to console shows me:

```
Object{ (...) }
  @categoryID: "123"
  @id: "234"
  categoryTitle: "abc"
  (...)
```

If I want to fetch the category title, I simply do `item.categoryTitle`. But if I want the ID, I can't use `item.id`.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034401/what-is-in-an-object-property), one can use `$object->{'@id'};`, but trying `$item->{'@id'}` is not working.

So how to I get this value?

Comment: If I understand your question correct I would go about using `item["@id"]` to get the value of @id.

Comment: The answer you linked was about PHP, not JavaScript.

Comment: Bergi, if it's a duplicate, pls link to the duplicate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer it using `['key']` syntax

```
var obj = { '@id' : 123 };
console.log(obj['@id']);   //123
```

Comment: This is called bracket notation (as opposed to dot notation)

Comment: Thanks. Do you also know why they use the `@`?

Comment: I'm sorry. I am not sure why they have used `@` prefix. But using bracket notation all string literals are valid key.