# Access a nested object array

Tags: php, oop, object

Hey guys I can't seem to get the syntax here right, I'm just trying to see if type exists,
I've tried

```
if($obj->type)    /* do something */
if($obj[0]->type) /* do something */
if($obj->type[0]) /* do something */
```

On this

```
stdClass::__set_state(
array(
   '0' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(
  array(
     'report_number' => '555',
     'type' => 'citrus',
     'region' => 'Seattle',
     'customer_number' => '9757',
     'customer' => 'The Name',
     'location' => 'West Seattle, WA',
     'shipper' => 'Yamato Transport',
     'po' => '33215',
     'commodity' => 'RARE',
     'label' => 'PRODUCE',
  )),
))
```

But just can't seem to get it right, I believe it has something to do with
[0] being an int instead of varchar but I have no idea....

Comment: Hav you tried `$obj->0->type`?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I would have thought $obj[0]['type'] - have you tried this?

Comment: Please try: `$obj->{0}->type`.

Comment: `$obj = (array)$obj; $obj = (array)$obj[0][0]; echo $obj[0]['type'];`

Comment: $obj->0->type doesn't work, it hates the literal zero for some stupid reason, Hakre that's corr, I figured it out right before I checked the post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output in your question is created by `var_export` which represents the data of the object as an `array`. But don't get mislead by that, it's in fact an object.

Object properties are accessed by this syntax:

```
$obj->property
```

In your case the property is named `0` which is hard for PHP to deal with in plain code as it's not a property name you could write right away like this:

```
$obj->0
```

Instead, you need to tell the PHP parser what the name is by enclosing it into `{}`:

```
$obj->{0}
```

You can then traverse further on to access the `type` property of `0`:

```
$obj->{0}->type
```

Hope this is helpful, the question comes up from time to time, this is a related one with more related links: [How do I access this object property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758449/how-do-i-access-this-object-property).

The PHP Manual has this documented, but not very obvious on the [*Variable variables* entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

> In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an ambiguity problem. That is, if you write `$$a[1]` then the parser needs to know if you meant to use `$a[1]` as a variable, or if you wanted `$$a` as the variable and then the `[1]` index from that variable. The syntax for resolving this ambiguity is: `${$a[1]}` for the first case and `${$a}[1]` for the second.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<?php
    if (property_exists($obj, 'type')) { 
        // Do something 
    }
?>
```