# how to get values from php array object

Tags: php

```
stdClass Object
([abc] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 10

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 11

                )

            )

)
```

I have declared one PHP array. Now I want to get value of id in php variable.
How I can get using foreach loop.

Comment: Please show more effort.  This is a mega-duplicate.

Comment: You can use following syntax, $myObject->abc[0]->id assuming your object name is $myObject

Comment: This question should be closed as a duplicate, not answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access a nested object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400576/access-a-nested-object-array)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
foreach($object->abc as $item)
{
    echo ($item->id);
}
```

Comment: But it gives me only first array id value

Comment: @Anil if you want to get all the values put it in a loop

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$id=$abc[0]->id;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on StackOverflow