# php simplexml_load_file with a dash ( - )

Tags: php, xml

Hi I'm struggling to get data from an xml file in php...

the xml file is here: http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/8bfac288-ccc5-448d-9573-c33ea2aa5c30?inc=release-groups

and so far after loading it into simplexml_load_file as $xml
I want to do something like this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/8bfac288-ccc5-448d-9573-c33ea2aa5c30?inc=release-groups";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$releasegrouplist = "release-group-list"; 
$releasegroup = "release-group";

$i = "0";
for ($i = 0; $i <= 30; $i++)
  {
   echo "release: " . $xml->artist->$releasegrouplist->$releasegroup[$i]->title;}
```

The problem arises when I try to use it in a for loop with an $i variable as shown above.

Any tips or easier ways to do this?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this syntax instead. This script works for me with the change below (PHP 5.3.6).

```
echo "release: " . $xml->artist->{'release-group-list'}->{'release-group'}[$i]->title;
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758449/how-do-i-access-this-object-property)

Comment: Thank you so much!
[and thanks for your patience to help me and lack of cynicism]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually told us what the problem is, but I'm guessing it's that you haven't read the [SimpleXML section in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), where it says

> Accessing elements within an XML document that contain characters not
> permitted under PHP's naming convention (e.g. the hyphen) can be
> accomplished by encapsulating the element name within braces and the
> apostrophe.