# I want to process a XML file In php

Tags: php, xml

This is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<searchresult>
  <query>file</query>
  <page-number>3</page-number>
  <start>20</start>
  <files-per-page>10</files-per-page>
  <files-approx-count>6361998</files-approx-count>
  <result-files>
    <file>
      <name>file 1</name>
      <description>
        descrp
      </description>
      <url>
        http://www.example.com
      </url>
    </file>
    <file>
      <name>file 2</name>
      <description>
        descrp 2
      </description>
      <url>
        http://www.example.com
      </url>
    </file>
  </result-files>
</search-result>
```

i tried the following code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
foreach ($xml as $xmls):
    $name =$xmls->name;
    $url =$xmls->url;
    echo $name.$url;
endforeach;
```

but no output please help.

Comment: No output usually means an error. Please post the error.

Comment: Shows a blank page but i can get the ELEMENT query using the code echo $xml->query ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, your XML file is not well-formed. The root tag is `<searchresult>` while the last tag is `</search-result>`. This causes a parsing error.

Second thing, if your tags contain dashes, those tags cannot be used directly as variables with *SimpleXML*, in that case you should use a special syntax (see this: [php simplexml_load_file with a dash ( - )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951753/php-simplexml-load-file-with-a-dash)). Other way to fix this is, if you control de XML syntax, change the way the XML is written and don't use dashes on tags.

Lastly, I think you want to print out the info of files within the `result-files` tag.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");

foreach ($xml->{'result-files'}->file as $file) {
    printFile($file);
}

function printFile($file) {
    $name = trim($file->name);
    $url = trim($file->url);
    print "$name $url\n";
}
```

Output:

```
file 1 http://www.example.com
file 2 http://www.example.com
```

And you are done.

Comment: +1 nice answer but not sure what the benefit of the printFile function is. Also I would explicitly cast as a string `$name = (string)$file->name;` because if you do anything other than echo it, it will remain as a SimpleXML element object.

Comment: No direct benefit :) I just wanted to make it more readable, like iterate through each file and do something with it. What to do? Print its name and url.

Comment: Thanks.. it worked , But i am unable to edit the XML file because its the output of another API from 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an object when you use the `simplexml_load_file`. The object isn't necessarily iterable - but it is indexable by tag names. try not doing the `foreach(...)` and instead just using `echo $xml->name;`. If that doesn't work, then perhaps you're looking in the wrong directory for your file. You likely need to do something like:

**EDITED TO MATCH XML FILE PROVIDED**

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/file.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($path);
echo $xml->start; //should output 20
```

Comment: please run the above code with MY XML file ( Result is no error no o/p )

Comment: I feel like you're just playing with someone else's code that you don't understand.. instead - learn and build your own code. Never grab and use code that doesn't make sense to you - or if you want to use it, learn how it works first.