# How to get xml attributes using php?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to get an attribute:

```
<Info  InstallPath="C:\Program Files\MyProg"  Version="1.0" >

    <Modules>
        <parser.exe Launched="Off" />
        <analyzer.exe Launched="On" />
    </Modules>

</Info>
```

I wrote:

```
echo $Parser = $xml->Info->Modules->parser.exe->attributes()->Launched;
```

But it does not work because "parser.exe" contains a dot

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: BTW the issue is quite common for starters, it is the same with a dash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951753/php-simplexml-load-file-with-a-dash - And the mistake to write out the name of the root element is also a common mistake. All these issues are well explained and nicely demonstrated in: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic (Example #2 and #3).

Answer (score 1):

If `<Info>` is your root element then:

```
echo $xml->Modules->{'parser.exe'}->attributes()->Launched;
```

Because of the `.` character in your `<parser.exe>` element, you need to use the `{}` syntax to access the property.

In SimpleXML, the object (`$xml`) refers to the root element, so `$xml->Info` is not necessary.