# json decode and property accessing fails

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access this object property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758449/how-do-i-access-this-object-property)

> stdClass Object ( [show_title] => [link_titles] => [show_intro] =>
>   [show_category] => [link_category] => [show_parent_category] =>
>   [link_parent_category] => [show_author] => [link_author] =>
>   [show_create_date] => [show_modify_date] => [show_publish_date] =>
>   [show_item_navigation] => [show_vote] => [show_icons] =>
>   [show_print_icon] => [show_email_icon] => [show_hits] => [show_noauth]
>   => [urls_position] => [menu-anchor_title] => [menu-anchor_css] => [menu_image] => [menu_text] => 1 [page_title] => [show_page_heading]
>   => 0 [page_heading] => [pageclass_sfx] => [menu-meta_description] => [menu-meta_keywords] => [robots] => [secure] => 0 )

That is the output of items after json-decode using print_r
I would like to access the property menu-anchor_css but I can't do something like this

```
$items=json_decode($item->params);
$class = $items->menu-anchor_css ? 'class="'.$items->anchor_css.'" ' : '';
$title = $items->menu-anchor_title ? 'title="'.$items->anchor_title.'" ' : '';
```

As it always displays me error message that `menu` is not defined. (The hyphen and underbar seem problematic here)

Thank you alot

Comment: `$items->menu-anchor_css` means `$items->menu - anchor_css`

Comment: Thanks, but how can I fix it now ?

Comment: @VladBalmos Thanks for finding that, flagging for close as duplicate.

Comment: Thank you, I'm loving it. Problem resolved by the above link by Vlad. I was just thinking I am going to get fired by the end of next weekend if I can't resolve these problems.