# Grabbing object property with a hashtag

Tags: php, object

I am trying to grab an object property that has a hashtag in the title. It comments out the rest of the line due to the hashtag.

The current code is:

```
if ($content->#title == 'News') {
```

I was thinking that maybe something like if ($content->{#title} == 'News') { would work, but that does not appear to work either. There has to be some way in PHP to access a property of an object with a hashtag on the front of it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($content->{'#title'} == 'News') {
```

Should do the trick. It at least compiles for me. [similar situation/source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758449/how-do-i-access-this-object-property-with-a-hyphenated-name?answertab=votes#tab-top)