# Laravel data is not getting inserted for some columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to insert the data in laravel where I want to insert 4 columns in DB - empid, name, in-time and out-time.

[image]

but i am getting syntax error 'unexpected =' for columns separated by **'-'** e.g: **in-time, out-time**.

Is there any way to allow inserting values for '-' separated columns in DB using laravel ?

Comment: Seems like this is only the text editor error, it shouldn't interfere with your saving method.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26016363/1281242

Comment: You should never use hyphens in your code. Go for underscores.

Comment: also I STRONG recommend to don't use hyphen on your DB column fields!

Comment: @Rehmat Why never use hyphens/dashes?

Comment: @kerbholz to avoid silly things like `$attendata->{'in-time'}`. What if he used underscores and updated the values with a simple `$attendata->in_time` rather using `$attendata->{'in-time'}`? Not only while saving the data, now he will have to do `$attendata->{'in-time'}` everywhere in the code where he needs this property's value. Makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use underscores for attributes names but you can still use it like this:

```php
$attendata->{'in-time'} = $col[8];
$attendata->{'out-time'} = $col[9];
```

Comment: Thanks @N69S. That solved my problem. Better to use underscores though

Answer (score 1):

Please remove hyphens(-) from your column fields. As the columns fields are treated as properties of the model which acts a variable. So if talk about the variable they can't have any special characters except (_). You can use `in_time` or `out_time` instead of using `in-time` or `out-time`.

Comment: `-` in properties are allowed though

Comment: to use (-) you need to follow different way to assign values just like @N69S 's answer.You can't write it straightly like Nikunj V has written. The best practice is to use underscores

Comment: I know, "_they can't have any special characters except (`_`)._" makes it sound like `-` isn't allowed, but it is