# PHP add value of 4 otp input field to get the final otp code given by the user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Here is my blade code to get otp input from the user

```
<input type="text" style="" id="digit-1" name="digit-1" data-next="digit-2" />
<input type="text" style="" id="digit-2" name="digit-2" data-next="digit-3" data-previous="digit-1" />
<input type="text" style="" id="digit-3" name="digit-3" data-next="digit-4" data-previous="digit-2" />
<input type="text" style="" id="digit-4" name="digit-4" data-next="digit-5" data-previous="digit-3" />
```

in my controller i want to get the merged value of the otp like this: ex- 1234
here is my controller code which shows error:

```
$user_given_otp=$request->digit-1.$request->digit-2.$request->digit-3.$request->digit-4;
```

Comment: You should avoid hyphen characters for php class properties, still there is a way to access it, check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758449/how-do-i-access-this-object-property-with-a-hyphenated-name

Answer (score 0):

try

```php
$user_given_otp=$request->get(digit-1).$request->get('digit-2').$request->get('digit-3').$request->get('digit-4');
```

or

```php
$user_given_otp=$request->{'digit-1'}.$request->{'digit-2'}.$request->{'digit-3'}.$request->{'digit-4'};
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use this for single digit on single input box

```html
<input type="text" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');">
```